# Performance issues when drawing multiple plots of the same solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, performance-tuning, manipulate

I defined a system of ODEs inside a `Manipulate` environment. I would like to draw multiple plots of *the same* `NDSolve` solution, i.e. I want to plot each variable separately. My code is pretty straightforward (see a little working example below), but I have performance issues.

My guess is that `NDSolve` is evaluated every time is called inside a `Plot`. Is there a way to avoid that? Am I doing something wrong (I am an absolute beginner with Mathematica)?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol, t, a, b, kb = 1.0},
  sol = NDSolve[
    {a'[t] == kb*b[t],
     b'[t] == -ka*b[t],
     a[0] == 0.1, b[0] == 0.1},
    {a, b}, {t, 0.0, 5.0}];
  GraphicsRow[{
    Plot[a[t] /. sol, {t, 0.0, 5.0}],
    Plot[b[t] /. sol, {t, 0.0, 5.0}]}
   ]
  ],
 {{ka, 1.0, "ka"}, 1.0, 100.0}
]
```

Comment: Since you're using `=` and not `:=` `NDSolve` shouldn't be recomputing when you plot. There might be a trick or two you could do to make this faster (e.g. prerender the plots for specific values of `ka` then just use manipulate to display parts: `plts=Table[Module[{...},sol=NDSolve[...];GraphicsRow[...]],{ka,1.0,100.,10.}]; Manipulate[plts[[i]],{i,1,Length@plts,1}]`) but this runs just as fast as I can move the slider on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use `DSolve` and solve the ODE once, then replace the parameter `ka` into the solution. Now it is very fast

```
Manipulate[

GraphicsRow[{
   Plot[a[t]/.sol/.{ka0->ka},{t,0.0,5.0}],
   Plot[b[t]/.sol/.{ka0->ka},{t,0.0,5.0}]
}
],
{{ka,1.0,"ka"},1.0,100.0},
TrackedSymbols:>{ka},
Initialization:>
{
  kb=1;
  sol=First@DSolve[{a'[t]==kb*b[t],b'[t]==-ka0*b[t],a[0]==1/10,b[0]==1/10},
     {a[t],b[t]},t]
}    
]
```

Notice that when using Initialization section in Manipulate, the symbols in there become global.

[image]

**Update**

To answer comment below. If there is no closed form solution, then the same thing can be done but using `ParametricNDSolve` as follows

```
Manipulate[

GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[a[ka][t]/.sol ,{t,0.0,5.0}],
  Plot[b[ka][t]/.sol ,{t,0.0,5.0}]
}
],
  {{ka,1.0,"ka"},1.0,100.0},
  TrackedSymbols:>{ka},

Initialization:>
{
  kb=1;
  sol=ParametricNDSolve[{a'[t]==kb*b[t],b'[t]== 
          - ka0*b[t],a[0]==1/10,b[0]==1/10},{a,b},{t,0,5},{ka0}]
}    
]
```

Comment: Works only if there is an closed-form solution to the ODE :)

Comment: @anderstood that is correct of course. The ODE given does have closed form solution. If there was no closed form solution, then `ParametricNDSolve` can be used. Will update now.